# NodeJS: Single object with all requires, or "standard" paths in code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

So, I'm a big fan of creating global namespaces in javascript. For example, if my app is named Xyz I normally have an object XYZ which I fill with properties and nested objects, for an example:

```
XYZ.Resources.ErrorMessage // = "An error while making request, please try again"
XYZ.DAL.City // = { getAll: function() { ... }, getById: function(id) { .. } }
XYZ.ViewModels.City // = { .... }
XYZ.Models.City // = { .... }
```

I sort of picked this up while working on a project with Knockout, and I really like it because there are no wild references to some objects declare in god-knows-where. Everything is in one place.

Now. This is ok for front-end, however, I'm currently developing a basic skeleton for a project which will start in a month, and it uses Node.

What I wanted was, instead of all the requires in .js files, I'd have a single object ('XYZ') which would hold all requires in one place. For example:

Instead of:

```
// route.js file
var cityModel = require('./models/city');
var cityService = require('./services/city');

app.get('/city', function() { ...........});
```

I would make an object:

```
XYZ.Models.City = require('./models/city');
XYZ.DAL.City = require('./services/city');
```

And use it like:

```
// route.js file
var cityModel = XYZ.Models.City;
var cityService = XYZ.DAL.City;

app.get('/city', function() { ...........});
```

I don't really have in-depth knowledge but all of the requires get cached and are served, if cached, from memory so re-requiring in multiple files isn't a problem.

Is this an ok workflow, or should I just stick to the standard procedure of referencing dependencies?

edit: I forgot to say, would this sort-of-factory pattern block the main thread, or delay the starting of the server? I just need to know what are the downsides... I don't mind the requires in code, but I just renamed a single folder and had to go through five files to change the paths... Which is really inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a bad idea, because you are going to serve a ton of modules every single time, and you may not need them always. Your namespaced object will get quite monstrous. `require` will check the module cache first, so I'd use standard requires for each request / script that you need on the server.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. So if in server.js or whatever it's named, I call "globals.XYZ = require('my-monstrous-object')", it will instantiate multiple times?

Comment: What do you mean "instantiate multiple times"? It will assign the `my-monstrous-object`module to `globals.XYZ`.

Comment: Oh, so what do you mean by "server a otn of modules every single time"?

Comment: Since `globals` is a global, it will have to be parsed at every single request / script. So in a file or script that requires zero modules, you're hitting performance by giving it every single thing.